# VSCode Java Debugger throwing error 'org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.ConnectImpl$StringArgumentImpl.<init>'

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have been working for a long time with a Spring Boot project in VS Code, but yesterday I bumped into this error when trying to launch the Java Debugger for this project.

A simple *run* mode is working fine but the *debug* mode is throwing the following error, for the same project, with the same `launch.json` configuration that I attach below:

[image: The error dialog and my launch.json config]

So far I've tried restarting VSCode and my computer, trying to relaunch the project as soon as the PC booted before any other app or service that could be using any port, but the error still occurs.

Please, can someone give me some clue on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the VS code extension, Reload the java debugger extension

Comment: This is on point, I had the same issue and I visited Extension panel, found that 'Debugger for Java' plugin was labelled "Reload required". I reloaded and re-built the code and was able to launch the debugger successfully.

Comment: Same for me. Just reloaded VSCode from the extension and the error disappeared. Thanks.

Comment: I had to install a newer version of the java debugger extension (press "ctrl + p" and execute "ext install vscode-java-debug").

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reload and re-install the plugins but that did not solve the issue for me. The 'Visual Studio IntelliCode' extension needed to be reloaded but that still did not fix my issue.

However, my application started when I commented out the console setting in launch.json. The app loaded in the Terminal window without issues. Also, I added the spring boot debug command into args. That seems to be necessary as well.

```
// "console": "internalConsole",
"args": "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000",
```

[image: launch.json]

I'm guessing this is actually bypassing the internal console but it works.

Also, externalTerminal seems to work as well.

```
"console": "externalTerminal",
```